# CSS масштабировать весь div под ширину экрана (transform scale)

Tags: css, stylus

Есть div блок с множеством элементов, включая картинки. Сейчас он по ширине вылазить за экран на малых экранах.

Задача - масштабировать его под ширину экрана, т.е. пропорционально уменьшить.

```
transform-origin left
transform scale(.3)
```

Проблема здесь в том, что не могу вместо .3 вставить, например, 1vw - это бы решило проблему.

**Возможно ли как-то сконвертировать vw (px) в число средствами css/stylus (что бы получилось как бы scale(1vw))?** Другие способы решения?

Javascript не может здесь быть использован, только css/stylus.

```
thumb_mw = 120px
thumb_mh = 80px
thumb_border = 2px

sectnsBrdr = 1px

vwidth = (thumb_mw + thumb_border * 2)px
vheight = (thumb_mh * 3 + thumb_border * 3 * 2)px
hwidth = (thumb_mw * 3 + thumb_border * 3 * 2)px
hheight = (thumb_mh + thumb_border * 2)px

mainImgGap = 8px

galWidth = hwidth + vwidth * 2 + mainImgGap
galHeight = vheight + hheight * 2 + mainImgGap
```

Это стили размеров моего "див".

Comment: Покажите пример в песочнице

Comment: @Piterden  здесь показывать нечего. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JmYVbN ВСЕ содержимое в див должно масштавироваться по ширине окна/экрана. Единица vw это решает, только ее бы в scale как-то вставить пропорцией...

Comment: https://codepen.io/denis_efremov/pen/wYKbvB Вы знаете, у вас не будет ничего получаться, пока вы не научитесь писать код аккуратно и с соблюдением стиля. Это не только уважение к окружающим, но и в первую очередь к самому себе.

Comment: А почему нельзя использовать JS?

Comment: Зачем такие танцы с бубном? Используйте просто max-width: 30%  или удобное вам значение. Браузер сам все рассчитает.

Comment: @RuslanSemenov У меня дивы с изображениями разной установленной высоты и ширины. Здесь max-width не уместно. Я не зря именно про scale писал.

Comment: Я бы посоветовал, сами изображения накладывать как bacgroung-image с размером cover, и тогда они все будут одного размера, что приятнее глазу, и решит проблему скейлов

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {margin: 0;}

.wrapper-wrap {display: block; width: 100wh; height: 100vh; overflow: auto;}

.wrapper {display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; overflow: hidden;}
.wrapper p, .wrapper h1 {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.wrapper p {display: block; width: 100%; height: 25px;}
.wrapper h1 {display: block; width: 100%; height: 40px;}
.wrapper img {display: block; width: 100%; height: calc(100% - 65px); object-fit: contain;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-wrap">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>
      <span>Ϯ</span>
      <a href="#">dkajckjsdbkvsdbk</a>
    </p>
    <img src='https://www.simtropolis.com/objects/screens/monthly_2018_09/Scr1.png.074054387d0b30669e9dfb259ac4377f.png' />
    <h1>TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT kabdsakdbaksd</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо,но это н сработает в моем случае... пробовал подобное. пока что самым надежным способом вижу scale, но пиксели туда не могу передать сконвертировав в просто число... чуть обновил свой вопрос с кодом размеров моих элементов.